# Requesting more permissions from LinkedIn API in 2020

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I am trying to get rw_organization_admin permission from LinkedIn API but I get an unauthorized scope error. I use 3-legged Oath and I am the organization administrator of course. Does anyone know how to apply for this permission because the LinkedIn API doc in not clear. Is this permission included in Marketing Platform API?

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I am not 100% sure about that and I am in the same situation.

What I know: As of my knowledge - yes, to get more permissions granted, you need to apply for at least one of the LinkedIn Partner Programs like Marketing Platform API. When you get approved you should have access to more permissions. To what permissions exactly? No idea! Documentation is here missing a lot!

In my example my request got declined with the reason "you got declined" and it seems like I can not apply me again for the program - great job LinkedIn!

I submitted a ticket in the LinkedIn Developer Support board that you can find here: https://linkedin.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/

Answer (score 0):

I got access to the rw_organization_admin last month. I created an app ([link](https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps)) and then submitted an application for access to the `Marketing Developer Platform` from the apps dashboard, once approved I got the rw_organization_admin permission (along with many others).

Comment: Did this also include the r_basicprofile permission?

Comment: Yes, r_basicprofile and r_liteprofile (and others).